# How to find max date from stream in scala using CompareTo?

Tags: scala, date, functional-programming, max

I am new to Scala and trying to explore how I can use Java functionalities with Scala.

**I am having stream of `LocalDate` which is a Java class and I am trying to find maximum date out of my list.**

```
var processedResult : Stream[LocalDate] =List(javaList)
      .toStream
      .map { s => {
        //some processing
        LocalDate.parse(str, formatter)
        }
      }
```

I know we can do easily by using `.compare()` and `.compareTo()` in Java but I am not sure how do I use the same thing over here.

Also, I have no idea how `Ordering` works in Scala when it comes to sorting.

Can anyone suggest how can get this done?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a lot of minor details that I will point out since it seems you are pretty new to the language and I expect those to help you with your learning path.

First, avoid `var` at all costs, especially when learning.
While mutability has its place and is not always wrong, forcing you to avoid it while learning will help you. Particularly, avoid it when it doesn't provide any value; like in this case.

Second, this `List(javaList)` doesn't do what you think it does. It creates a single element **Scala** `List` whose unique element is a **Java** `List`. What you probably want is to transform that **Java** `List` into a **Scala** one, for that you can use the [**CollectionConverters**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html).

```scala
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._ // This works if you are in 2.13
// if you are in 2.12 or lower use: import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val scalaList = javaList.asScala.toList
```

Third, not sure why you want to use a **Scala** `Stream`, a `Stream` is for infinite or very large collections where you want all the transformations to be made lazily and only produce elements as they are consumed *(also, btw, it was deprecated in `2.13` in favour of `LazyList`)*.
Maybe, you are confused because in **Java** you need a *"Stream"* to apply functional operations like `map`? If so, note that in **Scala** all collections provide the same rich API.

Fourth, `Ordering` is a [**Typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) which is a functional pattern for [**Polymorphism**](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4). On its own, this is a very broad question so I won't answer it here, but I hope the two links provide insight.
The TL;DR; is simple, it is just that an `Ordering` for a type `T` knows how to order *(sort)* elements of type `T`. Thus operations like `max` will work for any collection of any type if, and only if, the compiler can prove the existence of an `Ordering` for that type if it can then it will pass such value [*implicitly*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) to the method call for you; again the implicits topic is very broad and deserves its own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits/5598107#5598107).

---

Now for your particular question, you can just call `max` or `maxOption` in the `List` or `Stream` and that is all.
Note that `max` will throw if the `List` is empty, whereas `maxOption` returns an [`Option`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) which will be empty *(**None**)* for an empty input; idiomatic **Scala** favour the latter over the former.

If you really want to use `compareTo` then you can provide your own `Ordering`.

```scala
scalaList.maxOption(Ordering.fromLessThan[LocalDate]((d1, d2) => d1.compareTo(d2) < 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

`Ordering[A]` is a type class which defines how to compare 2 elements of type `A`. So to compare `LocalDate`s you need `Ordering[LocalDate]` instance.

`LocalDate` extends `Comparable` in Java and Scala conveniently provides instances for `Comparable`s so when you invoke:

```
Ordering[java.time.LocalDate]
```

in REPL you'll see that Scala is able to provide you the instance without you needing to do anything (you could take a look at the list of methods provided by this typeclass).

Since you have and `Ordering` in implicit scope which types matches the `Stream`'s type (e.g. `Stream[LocalDate]` needs `Ordering[LocalDate]`) you can call `.max` method... and that's it.

```
val processedResult : Stream[LocalDate] = ...
val newestDate: LocalDate = processedResult.max
```